# ASP.NET MVC Fullscreen and close Button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When I make the window go fullscreen how can I make the replacing location remain in fullscreen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="column-header">
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" id="btnFullScreen" name="btnFullScreen" value="Fullscreen" style="font-size:xx-large; font-weight:bold; width:500px; height:300px; text-align:center; background-color:#e87a3a; border-color:#3f464c" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#btnFullScreen").click(function () {
                location.replace("/Home/About");
                var el = document.documentElement,
                    rfs = el.requestFullscreen
                        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
                        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
                        || el.msRequestFullscreen
                    ;
                rfs.call(el);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And how can I make an application close button by fullscreen?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more what did it mean ` replacing location remain`?

Comment: When I change my view with "location.replace" the application doesn't stay in fullscreen

Comment: Oh I see, is it inside your application or other `web URL`?

Comment: It is in my application.

Comment: Could you please add that page `url` and `directory location`. It is possible to implement no worry.

Comment: The Url is: "http://localhost:50110/" and the directory location is "C:\Users\Oezbro\source\repos\PlaudertischWeb"

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC or model-view-controller.

Comment: It's in my Asp.Net MVC application

Comment: Okay I understand I am testing your case

Comment: @OEZBRO Try below way, hope it would help, let me know if you encounter any more problem. happy coding